# Flash plugin error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, flash, chromium

I have updated my Ubuntu to 16.04 a couple of days ago and now the Flash Player does not work with Chrome browser.

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

**Result**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk
Suggested packages:
  x-ttcidfont-conf msttcorefonts ttf-xfree86-nonfree xfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  adobe-flash-properties-gtk adobe-flashplugin
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/10.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 38.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 1425767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../adobe-flashplugin_1%3a20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking adobe-flashplugin (1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_1%3a20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/flash-player-properties.png', which is also in package flash-plugin 11.2.202.346-1
Preparing to unpack .../adobe-flash-properties-gtk_1%3a20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking adobe-flash-properties-gtk (1:20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_1%3a20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/flash-player-properties', which is also in package flash-plugin 11.2.202.346-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flashplugin_1%3a20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/adobe-flash-properties-gtk_1%3a20160712.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**update**

I do not know what had happened but I am not able to play video content with chrome browser after upgrade to 16.04. Everything was working fine before update. I can see a "could not load plugin" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that flash has already been installed by some other source. No need to try to install that software again.

In Ubuntu 16.04 flash will get auto-installed via updates. Separate installation is not needed.

To get rid of the conflict

Start Google Chrome, and then type chrome://plugins in the address bar.

Click Details and move to the Flash section.

Disable libpepflashplayer.so by unchecking the box

Restart the browser and see if you can view rich media content by accessing the web pages.

See

https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-google-chrome.html

Comment: I do not know what had happened but I am not able to play video content with chrome browser after upgrade to 16.04. Everything was working fine before update. I can see a "could not load plugin" error.

Comment: You may study the link help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111411, The conflict between built-in flash player and adobe flash player causes this conflict. Try disabling browser flash player

Comment: I like Ubuntu ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Chromium? Because Google Chrome does include Flash Player by default, Chromium does not. If you don't want to do that much with commands and terminals, I'd recommend to download Google Chrome from Google their official download page, and then double-clicking it to open it up with the Software Center. Or you could use the dpkg command in order to install the package.

Comment: OP is using chromium which does require officially maintained adobe flashplayer

Answer (score -1):

Chrome browser does not use the flash plugin you're trying to install at all, so you may as well uninstall it completely.  Chrome browser uses Pepper flash and it's embedded in the browser.  It gets installed during browser installation.  If it doesn't work, you have to check what's wrong with Chrome installation.

You can reset your Chrome installation to default settings for example by deleting these two directories using a terminal window:

`rm -R ~/.config/google-chrome`
`rm -R ~/.cache/google-chrome`.

If this doesn't work, you may need to re-install Chrome.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash, pepper-flash has been depreciated in favor of officially maintained adobe flash

Comment: Also OP saaid about chrome browser, not google-chrome

Comment: You are wrong.  Chrome supports only pepper plugins now.  It is pepper flash.  It has removed support for the previous NPAPI protocol.  The plugin you are mentioning is not the one embedded in Chrome.  We are talking about two different plugins.

Comment: Study my link, pepper flash has been depreciated, also my link is about not google chrome, its about chromium